# rewrite background with active class css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have few div and all are red in color, I use 'red' as the class name. but among the div I want to apply extra class like class="red active" to give selected div extra style.

why this doesn't work

```
.red{
   background: red;
}

.red .active{
   background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your css for :

```
.red.active
```

Answer (score 4):

`.red .active` (with a space between) means an element that has a class `active` and is the descendant (children, granchildren, etc.) of an element that has a class `red`. This is called the [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors).

You need `.red.active` (without a space). It means an element that has both a `red` and `active` class. This is a multiple class selector.

Recommended read:

[Multiple Class / ID and Class Selectors from Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/)